# Having trouble getting Flask app running on cPanel using passenger_wsgi.py

Tags: python, flask, cpanel, web-hosting

I'm trying to get a Flask "point of sale" application working on cPanel with no success.

Here is the directory structure on cPanel File Manager

[image: file structure]

I have my app = Flask(**name**) in **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_security import Security,SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
# from app.models import Role,User

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db, render_as_batch=True)
login = LoginManager(app)


from app import routes,models
```

I have tried using the line this line of code in my passenger_wsgi.py

```
from app import app as application
```

and in my pointofsale.py i used:

```
application = app
```

I have successfully created the python app and installed requirements.txt, when I try to load the link to the website but I cant reach the site.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure out the issue, I had two files importing the application instance -: **pointofsale.py** and **passenger_wsgi.py**.
I deleted **pointofsale.py**, and added the following code to passenger_wsgi.py file

```
from app import app
application = app
```

Comment: I think it's also possible to specify the entrypoint file when creating the python app from the cPanel console